# Quarkus: Inject config properties into annotation parameters

Tags: quarkus

Currently, we use the `@Scheduled` annotation from `quarkus-scheduler` to periodically execute a method:

```
@Scheduled(every = "10s")
void sync() {
  ...
}
```

I would like to make the interval configurable in `application.properties`. Is there a way to inject a configuration property into the value of the `every` parameter? E.g. something like `@Scheduled(every = "${sync.interval}")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **every** attribute supports Property Expressions including default values and nested Property Expressions.

(Note that "{property.path}" style expressions are still supported but don’t offer the full functionality of Property Expressions.)

**Interval Config Property Example**

```
@Scheduled(every = "${myMethod.every.expr}")
void myMethod() { }
```

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#property-expressions

https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler-reference#intervals