# How do Quarkus property expressions work in Kotlin annotations?

Tags: kotlin, properties, quarkus

i am wondering how i can use [property expressions](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#property-expressions) within annotation with kotlin.

In Java we can use config properties as attributes of annotations using:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeJavaClass {

    @Inject
    @StorageBackend(implementation = "${storage.backend}")
    StorageBackendInterface storageBackend;
}
```

in kotlin this syntax is the same as the string interpolation and cannot be used here.

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class SomeKotlinClass {

    @Inject
    @StorageBackend(implementation = "${storage.backend}") // <-- string interpolation takes place, leads to compile time error
    private lateinit var storageBackend: StorageBackendInterface
}
```

I also tried to auto-convert it using Intellij which leads to something like that, where the '$' is escaped but then quarkus doesn't recognizes it as an property expression:

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class SomeKotlinClass {

    @Inject
    @StorageBackend(implementation = "\${storage.backend}") // the '$' is escaped, not resolved during runtime
    private lateinit var storageBackend: StorageBackendInterface
}
```

```
# application.properties
%int.storage-backend=redis
%dev.storage-backend=in-memory
```

So whats the right approach resolving config properties as annotation attributes with kotlin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IntelliJ is correct, escaping the `$` will lead to the literal string `${storage.backend}` in the annotation value. If Quarkus/Spring then doesn't recognize it, that's a different problem, which has nothing to do with Kotlin or string interpolation. Perhaps it has to do with the property name itself? (`.` vs `-`). I also don't see an indication in the documentation you linked, that those property expressions will work in annotations.

Comment: You are right that's not in the linked documentation. The information that it works is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75821857/quarkus-inject-config-properties-into-annotation-parameters. And it works java pretty well.
And yes, it seems to be a problem with the quarkus-kotlin, and I was hoping anyone else already have an solution for this ;)

Comment: Ok, I have to correct myself. It only works for some Annotations (Like `@Scheduled.cron`), not generally.